# How to calculate a column value using a value from a previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to Python and Pandas, learning how to handle some data without using the FOR LOOP approach.

I have a DataFrame which contains 3 columns:

1. Date
2. Price
3. Increase

How can I calculate the price increase from the previous day to today (without using a FOR loop)?

From what I could read in some articles, the solution seems to go in the direction of using the shift function, but not clear to me how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `shift`. You can just use `diff`:

```
df["Increase"] = df["Price"].diff()
```

Comment: That is easy! :) Thanks!